# Microsoft Arc Touch mouse doesn't want to connect in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: bluetooth, high-sierra, mouse, microsoft

I've been able to pair a Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse Surface with my MacBook ever since Yosemite, but when I updated to High Sierra the mouse stop connecting. When I turn on the mouse, the Bluetooth sensor just flashes and the LED light below the scroll turns green and then red. Normally this is an indication that I need to change the batteries, but I have already changed them by new ones. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

After a while, the mouse starts working with the next solution, but still, I don't know if it will fail again.

1. In System Preferences > Bluetooth at the devices list, delete
   mouse and keyboard pairing (maybe keyboard was in conflict, I
   don't know)
2. Pair the mouse. Turn on, press the Bluetooth button, wait for the device to be identified and connect.
3. Then turn on the
   keyboard and connect.

Comment: The problem wasn't solved at all, I need to do this every morning, so any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: Is the vendor of the mouse no help whatsoever? Apple’s Bluetooth mice should be able to pair with your Mac to ensure your Bluetooth stack is working.

Answer (score 1):

I get the mouse working with macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 by pairing it a few times per day, as it is going to sleep constantly, never reconnecting on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The Specifications page in the Microsoft Web site for the mouse Arc Touch Bluetooth Mouse now indicates it is compatible with MacOS 10.13. I have upgraded to 10.13.3 but still the mouse does not work. When I called MS Support, the representative told me that Apple was going to release a patch to make 10.13 compatible with the Arc Touch BT Mouse, and that I should wait.

Comment: I still cannot get my arch touch mouse to connect with my MacBook running 10.13.5 (17F77) after a reboot.

Comment: @JohnArmwood Bummer. I don’t think that MS should say Apple has to release a patch since Bluetooth pointer protocol is super stable and works really well with multiple vendors. At best, if somehow Apple were to release a patch, the vendor should tell you exactly which version of MacOS has the required patch and support you until it’s working (but then in an ideal world, all support would be thusly)